# S3 response time differs when uploading via API vs AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I upload an image via AWS Console UI (webapp), response times of fetching the JPG file are 80-100ms. When I upload the same image to the same path using a PHP SDK, the response times of fetching the JPG file are 300-500ms.

This is very odd, any ideas? I checked response headers, both the same, no gzip on either. Gzip possible with S3?

I've never used S3 before, will the 80ms response times be consistent?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the time difference realized in time taken for te transfer, or overhead before/after the transfer by the SDK and webapp?

Comment: I clarified my question, talking about fetching the files, not the upload. The files are the exact same size.

Comment: How are you fetching the file? Are you doing a request directly to the s3 url? How are you measuring the fetch time?

Comment: Direct s3 url, https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/file_name.jpg. Measuring time with Chrome Dev Tools

Comment: Ah it seems like using http://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com is a lot faster than s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/